# show product slug only without id in url

Tags: node.js, express

I have a list of classifieds and when a user clicks on one it takes them to the detail page. I just want the slug in the url ie:

https://someshop.com/red-bag

I am able to do this but the problem is that the product names are not unique as more than one user may want to add a 'red bag' at some point. So, what I have done is used the ID and the slug eg:

https://someshop.com/4d35c2fcef9b6c17167ff53y/red-bag

But that doesn't look particularly nice. Is there a way to still check against the ID but not actually show it in the url?

html href:

```
<a href="/products/<%= product._id %>/<%= product.titleSlug %>" class="listing-item-container">
```

router:

```
router.get('/products/:productId/:titleSlug', shopController.getProductDetail);
```

Controller:

```
exports.getProductDetail = (req, res, next) => {
    const titleSlug = req.params.titleSlug;
    const productId = req.params.productId;
    Product.findOne({titleSlug: titleSlug, _id: productId})
    .then(product => {
        res.render('shop/product-detail', {
            pageTitle: 'Product detail',
            path: '/products',
            product: product
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is controlling the slug on the server side based on a `title` string received from the user and using a slug library of your choice. Then you can check your existing entries and make sure your slug is unique - worst case you just add something to it: you can have `/red-bag`, `/red-bag-1` and so on. Still nicer than UUIDs.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently taking the title and turning it into a slug. I suppose you are right, just changing it to red-bag-1 would still look nice than having the ID in the url.